# Overwriting / Decorating an ES6 Class from a module

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to overwrite a class from a module (connect-mongo). The module roughly works like this:

In `server.js`:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

// ...
app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

The module's source `index.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (connect) {
    const Store = connect.Store || connect.session.Store
    const MemoryStore = connect.MemoryStore || connect.session.MemoryStore

    class MongoStore extends Store {
        constructor(options) {
          // construction logic
        }

        methodA() {
          // method logic
        }

        // More props and methods
    }

    return MongoStore;
}
```

I would like to find a way of overwriting the module's `methodA()` and decorating the class with my own methods, too.

I have tried creating a `myPatch.js` file where I try to overwrite `MongoStore`, but I cannot seem to. I am particularly confused by how the `MongoStore` class is constructed dynamically based on the `connect` param, and I do not know how to get around this.

What would be the best way to change and add methods within the `MongoStore` class?

Comment: Can you edit `server.js` or not?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I can edit everything. If possible I'd tuck the patch in its own file, but that's it.

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like you're trying to extend that class which would be the sensible OOP thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to mutate/extend the class object that the dynamic construction returned.

```
// server.js:
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('patched-connect-mongo')(session);
…
```

```
// patched-connect-mongo.js
const originalConnectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
module.exports = function (session) {
    const OriginalMongoStore = originalConnectMongo(session);
    …
    // here, either OriginalMongoStore.prototype.methodA = function(…) { … };
    //          and return OriginalMongoStore
    // or do return class MyMongoStore extends OriginalMongoStore { methodA(…) { … } };
};
```

Comment: This is exactly the pattern that was eluding me - it's working now, thanks. Just a minor clarification, in `server.js` I should actually do `const MongoStore = require('/route/to/mypatch.js')(sessions)` , correct? That's what makes sense to me and how I've gotten it to work at least.

Comment: Oops, forgot to adjust that, yes indeed.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to create your own class that extends the `MongoStore` and then edit the properties you want.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

class MyCustomMongoStore extends MongoStore {

  constructor(props) {
    // pass any properties to MongoStore class (eg. connection)
    super(props);
    // add your own properties
    this.customProp = props.customProp;
  }

  methodA() {
    // your logic
  }

  customMethod() {
    // your method
  }
}

// ...
app.use(session({
  store: new MyCustomMongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    customProp: yourCustomProperty
  })
}));
```